# extend matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, realloc

I have a matrix in C and I want to create another one which has double rows than the first matrix.Those added rows I want to have the values of first matrix ,but with changed sign. I am trying to understand dynamic allocation,and I don't understand where I am wrong. The error that compiler says is that:"`invalid conversion from void* to int*"` . Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int *extend_matrix=NULL;
int *matrix=NULL;
int *negative_matrix=NULL;
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,m,n;
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of  matrix\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    int *matrix = (int *)malloc(m * n * sizeof(int));
    int *negative_matrix=(int*)malloc(m*n*sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter the elements of first matrix\n");
    for (  i = 0 ; i < m ; i++ )
        for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ )
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
    for(i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
        for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
            printf("the matrix is: \n",matrix[i][j]);
    negative_matrix=-matrix[i][j];
    for(i=0;i<m+m;i++)
        extend_matrix[i]=realloc(matrix[i],sizeof(int)*(m+m));
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        extend_matrix[j]=realloc(matrix[j],sizeof(int)*n);
    extend_matrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j]+negative_matrix[i][j];//how to concatenate them?
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are multiple problems in your code. You're saying `int *matrix` and then referring to it as `matrix[i][j]`. That can't work. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: After having declared `matrix` as `int *matrix`, `matrix[i][j]` seems nasty, it shouldn't even compile. As for concatenation: it depends on how your matrix is layed out - you can use your own loop or simply `memcpy()`.

Comment: I'm saying int * matrix,but then how can I add values to it? I don't know.

Comment: The error message strongly suggests you're compiling it as C++. Don't compile C code as C++, that will only cause grief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're a little confused. Let me to write a short example code

EDIT:
Ok, go [here](http://pastebin.com/v9RwdLS0)

There you'll find my example. I've not completed it, but just gave an input on how to finish it.

Note this, too:

From 66 to 68 line we have this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    free(first_matrix[i]);
}
```

This is because each elements of our matrix is a pointer and all them point to an array allocated on the heap. So, if you just freed first_matrix, like this:

```
free(first_matrix);
```

you would have freed only first_matrix from its own content on the heap (and not that one of each its element)